# Why does a pyplot window behave differently when it is generated from a stand-alone function vs. a function called from an event handler?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4, qtgui

When I run my `setup_plot` and `dataq` functions on their own the pyplot window behaves as expected, i.e. after the run finishes the buttons (pan/zoom etc) in the navigation toolbar are active. However, when I import the functions and call them from a button event handler in my main program the pyplot window stays active after the run finishes: it is still accepting data and the toolbar buttons are inactive. How should I stop plotting without closing the plot window? Here is a snippet:

```
class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QWidget, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
       self.setupUi(self)
       self.pushButton_Run.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_run_clicked)
       self.pushButton_Stop.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_stop_clicked)

    def pushbutton_run_clicked(self):
        # get line edit values here 
        functions.setup_plot()
        functions.dataq(steptime, runtime, CO2_1, CO2_2)
```

Comment: Do you think you could produce a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It is difficult to pinpoint the problem from the limited amount of information we have presently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem by creating a simple MCVE based on the code snippet you gave us. The only thing I could find that would make my simple application to behave as you described is if I do not set the `backend` of matplotlib to `Qt4Agg`.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(MyWindowClass, self).__init__(parent)

       pushButton_Run = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
       pushButton_Run.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_run_clicked)

       layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
       layout.addWidget(pushButton_Run, 0, 0)
       self.setLayout(layout)

    def pushbutton_run_clicked(self):

        fig, ax = setup_plot()                        
        dataq(fig, ax)

def setup_plot():

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.canvas.manager.show()

    return fig, ax

def dataq(fig, ax):
    for i in range(200):
        ax.plot(np.random.rand(1), np.random.rand(1), 'o')
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
    mywindow = MyWindowClass()
    mywindow.show()      
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

### Update - Second Example:

This is another way to setup your artists that may allow you to more easily used them within multiple functions and can make their manipulation more convenient.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(MyWindowClass, self).__init__(parent)

       #---- generate some data ----

       self.x = np.random.rand(50)
       self.y = np.random.rand(50)

       #---- create a layout ----

       pushButton_Run = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
       pushButton_Run.clicked.connect(self.pushbutton_run_clicked)

       pushButton_Clear = QtGui.QPushButton('Clear')
       pushButton_Clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_plot)

       layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
       layout.addWidget(pushButton_Run, 0, 0)
       layout.addWidget(pushButton_Clear, 1, 0)
       self.setLayout(layout)

       #---- init artists ----

       self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
       self.fig.canvas.manager.show()

    def clear_plot(self):
        self.ax.cla()
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()

    def pushbutton_run_clicked(self):
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.ax.cla()   
        dataq(self.fig, self.ax, self.x, self.y)
        dataq2(self.fig, self.ax, self.x, self.y)
        self.setEnabled(True)

def dataq(fig, ax, x, y):            
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ax.plot(x[i], y[i], 'o')
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()

def dataq2(fig, ax, x, y):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        ax.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], '-')
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
    mywindow = MyWindowClass()
    mywindow.show()      
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Changing the backend setting had no effect for me: your example worked both ways. However, the structure of your code revealed my mistake. I had defined `fig` and `ax` outside of `setup_plot` because they were used by multiple functions. Moving them inside fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Drew Glad it helped. Do you mean by "defined fig and ax outside of setup_plot" that they were defined as global variables?

Comment: Yes they were defined globally in `functions`. I'm working on cleaning this up. As you can probably tell I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Drew Ah ok, I understand. You can still define `fig` and `ax` outside of `setup_plot` if you want and if it allows you to more easily used them within multiple functions. I've updated my answer with a second example that shows how this could be done by defining your artists as class variables.

Comment: Using class variables as you suggested works for me. Thanks again!